# Date fixed but variable month and year in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have below code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

c0 = date.today()
c1 = c0 - relativedelta(months=1)
c2 = c0 - relativedelta(months=2)
c3 = c0 - relativedelta(months=3)
c4 = c0 - relativedelta(months=4)
c5 = c0 - relativedelta(months=5)
```

Now date today is 2023/06/14, however what I am trying to achieve is that no matter what date it is, I should get 16 as day, and actual current month and year.

I have tried adding int to current date but since current date is not fixed, I am not able to get 16 as day.

Please suggest a way where I can convert below to a date:

```
day = 16
month = datetime.now().month
year = datetime.now().year
date = year/month/day
```

Comment: Just set `c0.day = 16`.  The rest should just work.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, they're demonstrating the need to change the day component to something other than today.

Comment: @TimRoberts The `datetime` module's objects are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.replace()` (on [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace), [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)) to edit the day component:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().replace(day=16)
datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 16, 8, 35, 18, 558127)
>>> datetime.date.today().replace(day=16)
datetime.date(2023, 6, 16)
```